# python cricket game

Tags: python

I would really appreciate some help with a python program. It's a cricket program;asks user for number of overs to play then keep track of runs, wickets out and overs. That part is OK but I can't figure how to keep track of each batter and there runs.Only 1 batter can get out at one time and they swap the striker end after each over and obviously for odd runs. Please help if you can.
Here is the part of the program so far I just need to add the batters.

```
for overs in range(1, numOvers + 1): 

  if endGame: #.........set to true from inner loop when breaking
            break

    print()
    print("---------------------------")
    print("Enter runs for over ", overs)
    print("---------------------------")

    #inner loop for number of balls in the over 
    for _runs in range(1, BALLS_IN_OVER + 1): 

      #calculate the number of overs and remainding balls
      totalBallsFaced += 1 
      totalOversFaced = (totalBallsFaced // BALLS_IN_OVER)    
      partOverFaced = (totalBallsFaced % BALLS_IN_OVER) 

      #print()
      runs = int(input("> ")) #...........prompt user for runs

      if runs < 0:#.......................if negative number, add to 1 to wicket
        wicket += 1
        print("Batter out...")

        if wicket >= 10:#...............if batter out and if all batters out then team out
          print("Batters all out")
          endGame = 1 #..............set to true
          break #.......................break to outer loop
      else: 
        total += runs #..................if input >= 0 , add to total
```

---

Thanks for the fast feedback guys I took both ideas into consideration and finally finished.
Only batter with index 1 scores and batter index 2 is the other batter, with odd runs they just swap.

Comment: In Cricket, it's Batsman not batter.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea how to play cricket, but I might be able to help.

> "I can't figure how to keep track of each batter and there runs.Only 1
>   batter can get out at one time and they swap the striker end after
>   each over and obviously for odd runs."

If you're trying to keep track of all your batters, why not just use an array of tuples?
So each entry in the array will have (batter,runs,out,striker)

With `batter` holding the batter's number (can be removed and just use the array position 0 for the first batter and 1 for the second etc. Depends on whether or not you want to store a name or something for each batter),

`runs` holding how many runs they got,

`out` being a boolean `True` if they are out, `False` if they're still in,

and `striker` another boolean (I don't know cricket but it sounds like you said they take turns so one of them needs to be striker while the rest are not.)

Then you can only keep counting runs if `out` is `False` or however cricket rules work.

```
arr=[]
for i in range (num_of_batters):
     batter=input("Batter's name: ").strip()
     arr.append((batter,0,False,False))
```

Hope it helps

Comment: if you have no idea how to play cricket, then you have missed out, my friend!  ;-) However, +1 for trying to help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you need a list - each entry in the list would be the number of runs for a given batter.  so your code might look something like:

```
runsPerBatter = [0] * 11 # this makes a list with 11 zero entries
```

you can use the `wicket` variable to indicate which batter (list indexes start at 0, so when `wicket` is 0, we have the first batter, and we will put their runs in `runsPerBatter[0]`):

```
...
else:
  total += runs
  runsPerBatter[wicket] += runs
```

then at the end of the program you can print the runs per batter:

```
for i in range(11):
    print 'batsman', i + 1, 'made', runsPerBatter[i], 'runs'
```